# couldn't update git via git clone comand

Tags: software-installation, git

I was following through [the git documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git) and installed Git using source code package. Now, after installing Git, I want to update it (Though it might be unnecessary at this time, I simply want to try and make sure it works). I ran the command `git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git` and it returned error `-bash: /usr/bin/git: No such file or directory`. Reason might be obvious, since for installing git, I used the command `make prefix=/usr/local install` which installed Git in `/usr/local/bin/git`

Now, how to fix this?

I tried the same git clone command with `--git-dir=/usr/local/bin/git` which returned the same error `-bash: /usr/bin/git: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What does `hash` say? Did you have a `/usr/bin/git` previously and then removed it? That would lead to `bash: /usr/bin/git: No such file or directory` while `hash` still believes `git` to be there.

The solution in this case would be to either use a new shell. Or for each shell with the old hash, reset it using `hash -r`.

Comment: Yes.. I removed one previously.. hash-r worked like a charm.. marking the thread as resolved.. Thank you so much.

Comment: Another doubt.. The doc says there will be a /etc/gitconfig file.. but I can't find any. Any idea, why it is so?

Comment: A global `/etc/gitconfig` is optional, usually each user has his/her own `~/.gitconfig`. Depends on your situation.

Comment: In case, if I need one, I shall create it myself? the global config gile..

Comment: @BeingGokul if you used prefix, the file should be read in `/usr/local/etc/gitconfig` and/or `/etc/gitconfig`. Depends the options at configure time.

Answer (score 2):

Go back and rebuild it without the argument to `make`.  If you want to set the prefix directory, you need to do it with `configure`, but it defaults to /usr/local anyhow.